# Extraction of Face From the picture

Tags: android, eclipse, image, image-processing

i wanted to add something to my android application. That is editing the getup of the person. Like he takes a picture from the camera. Now i remove everything in the picture other than the face. Am using the help of this link for this problem:

```
http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-2-OpenCV-for-Android-Setup-Windows-API8.pdf
```

Now its taking much time to research on this. I was just thinking that i should ask the experts here that am i going in the right direction? Are there any other made solutions to solve this problem? like extracting face from the picture to the accurate most level. Any other suggestions for this work? After that i intend to change the hair styles of the person with the picture!

Comment: Yes, OpenCV is a good start for this. Don't expect this to be "easy". This isn't trivial and will take significant time to implement, especially if you have never done anything like that and lack understanding of CV.

Comment: sir have u ever built opencv for android?? if u can help me out with one of the steps am stuck with in the tutorial i shared

Comment: You can follow the instructions here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html
or use JavaCV. Unfortunately, I have too much contract-work to spend more time on here.

Answer (score -3):

You can use V&J face detector from OpenCV, but it works mainly for profile and near-profile faces.

If you're willing to consider options outside of OpenCV, you should take a look at this blog post which summarizes 48 face detection and recognition libraries:

http://blog.mashape.com/post/53379410412/list-of-40-face-detection-recognition-apis

Comment: does this support android too?? ofcourse opencv is kind of bothering me much in the building process!

Comment: I'm not familiar with incorporating OpenCV with android.

Comment: am asking about the link you shared. does it also have android libraries??

Comment: Why the hell did I got a reputation deduction (-1) on this answer?